# While Statement with Min & Max python

Tags: python

```
while True:
    reply = raw_input("Enter text, (type [stop] to quit): ")
    print reply.lower()
    if reply == 'stop':
        break
    x = min(reply)
    y = max(reply)
    print("Min is " + x)
    print("Max is " + y)
```

I'm trying to make a statement containing a while statement where it asks a series of input statements and takes them all and finds the min and max of all of the inputted numbers. Anyone have any solutions? I've been trying to work through the issue for a while without any luck. Thanks all!

Comment: If you want calculate the min/max of all values you have to keep track of the values (at least of their min and max) somehow.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a work request.

Comment: I've gotten to the point where I keep all of the entered variables in the output, but whenever I try to get the min and max, I receive letters from the "stop" as the min and max. Since stop is the break in the while statement. I've got to find some type of solution for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another approach.

```
while True:
    reply = raw_input("Enter numbers separated by commas. (type [stop] to quit): ")
    user_input = reply.split(',')
    if reply == 'stop':
        break
    x = map(float, user_input)
    y = map(float, user_input)
    values = (x, y)
    print("Min is " + str(min(x)))
    print("Max is " + str(max(y)))
```

Input:

`5, 10, 5000`

Output:

```
Enter numbers separated by commas. (type [stop] to quit): 5, 10, 5000
Min is 5.0
Max is 5000.0
Enter numbers separated by commas. (type [stop] to quit):
```

Answer (score 0):

Indentation is important in Python. As for the `min` and `max`, you could have two variable that keeps track of these numbers and continue requesting numbers until the stopping condition.

```
min = max = userInput = raw_input()
while userInput != "stop":
    if int(userInput) < int(min):
        min = int(userInput)
    elif int(userInput) > int(max):
        max = int(userInput)
    userInput = raw_input()
    print "Min is "+str(min)
    print "Max is "+str(max)
```

Here, the first input is taken as the `min` and `max` value. Note that if the user enters `stop` for the first value, `min` and `max` will also be `stop`. It'll be better if you clarified more constraints for user inputs.

Answer (score 0):

As they mentioned, you need to keep a track of the `list` to get the `min` and `max`. Following your code structure :

```
l = []
while True:
    reply = raw_input("Enter text, (type [stop] to quit): ")
    print reply.lower()
    if reply == 'stop':
        break
    l.append(int(reply))        #store the values

x = min(l)
y = max(l)
print "Min is ", x 
print "Max is ", y
```

**IMP :** Do not forget the `int` conversion

Another `space conservative` method you can try is to compute the min and max as you get the input.

```
import sys
#placeholders
maximum = -(sys.maxint) - 1     #highest negative value
minimum = sys.maxint     #highest positive value

while True:
    reply = raw_input("Enter text, (type [stop] to quit): ")
    print reply.lower()
    if reply == 'stop':
        break
    reply=int(reply)
    if reply<minimum :
        minimum = reply
    if reply>maximum :
        maximum = reply

print "Min is ", minimum
print "Max is ", maximum
```

Answer (score 0):

Your line of thinking was correct. You haven't used min max as variable names, which is great too. If u r using python 3, replace the **input** keyword with **raw_input**  in the below code.

Hope it worked! :)

```
minn=5000;
maxx=0;
while True:
    reply = input("Enter text, (type [stop] to quit): ")

    if int(reply) < int(minn):
        minn = int(reply)

    if int(reply) > int(maxx):
        maxx = int(reply)

    if reply == 'stop':
        break
    print("Min is " + str(minn))
    print("Max is " + str(maxx))
```